# Sending message from background.js to popup.js without listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, listener, message-queue

I have a long task that is running in `background.js`, and I want to send a message to `popup.js` upon completion. However, if the page action has not been clicked when the message is sent, the listener in `popup.js` will not yet have been registered, and the message will not be received.

I could instead send a message from `popup.js` and request the background task's result in response. However, there is no guarantee that the task will have finished at that point in time.

The only solution I see is a combination of the two: setting up a listener in both files and sending messages back and forth, saying things like: "Here's the result if you can hear me!" and "I can hear now! Send me a result if you're finished." However, this solution seems overly complex for such a simple task.

**So**, isn't there some place where `background.js` can place the result for `popup.js` to retrieve at its own leisure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. store it an a global variable in a **persistent** background page, the use of which is [officially discouraged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) for the obvious reason of memory efficiency.

   background.js:

   ```
   var status;
   ```

   popup.js, method 1, asynchronous, preferred:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bg) {
       displayStatus(bg.status);
   });
   ```

   popup.js, method 2, synchronous:

   ```
   if (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().status) {
       displayStatus(bg.status);
   });
   ```
2. use [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) or [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (the latter stringifies everything but your code will be a little bit more concise due to being synchronous).
3. use the normal sendMessage communication, there's nothing overly complex in it:

   background.js:

   ```
   var taskCompleted = false;

   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
       if (message.request == "checkStatus") {
           sendResponse({done: taskCompleted});
       }
   });

   .................

   if (taskCompleted) {
       chrome.runtime.sendMessage({done: true});
   }
   ```

   popup.js:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({request: "checkStatus"}, function(response) {
       if (response.done) {
           doSomething();
       }
   });

   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
       if (message.done) {
           doSomething();
       }
   });
   ```